# ActionController::UrlGenerationError: missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm running RSpec 3 tests and am getting this same error for this one particular path:

```
 Failure/Error: visit book_path
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
 No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"books"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

My test isn't quite finished, so I'm sure some of the latter code might be incorrect. But I can't get my visit path line to run:

```
...
book = FactoryGirl.build(:book)
reviews = FactoryGirl.build_list(:review, 5, book: book)

visit book_path

reviews.each do |review|
  expect(page).to have_content(review.rating)
  expect(page).to have_content(review.body)
  expect(page).to have_content(review.timestamp)
end

  expect(page).to have_content('House of Leaves')
  expect(page).to have_content('Mark Z. Danielewski')
  expect(page).to have_content('Horror')
end
```

In my controller, I have show defined as:

```
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  @reviews = @book.reviews.order('created_at DESC')
  @review = Review.new
end
```

And my resources:

```
resources :books, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create] do
  resources :reviews, only: [:show, :new, :create] do
end
```

Answer (score 6):

It's raising an error because you haven't defined *which* book you'd like to visit. The missing key, `id`, is the ID of the book. So you should change this to:

```
book = FactoryGirl.build(:book)
reviews = FactoryGirl.build_list(:review, 5, book: book)

visit book_path(book)
```

Note that you can pass in the ID directly (`book_path(book.id)`),  but if you don't Rails will infer it from the object passed.

Comment: Ok, I passed in both and (book.id) gives me a less tangled error message. With (book_path(book.id)), I get:                               "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"books", :format=>nil, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]"

Comment: You're `build`ing the book, so it won't be assigned an ID (because it isn't saved to the database yet). Change it to `FactoryGirl.create(:book)` and you should be good.

Comment: Oh! Okay, I didn't realize that with build you don't get an id, just with create. That fixed it, thank you so much!